# Database error IN .NET Code

Tags: c#, .net, function, stored-procedures

I am getting an error as follows :-

> Procedure or function 'GetDetails' expects parameter '@Number', which
>   was not supplied.

Upon debugging , I found that function is getting the values . But I am not sure how to rectify this error . I am unable to understand how to supply values  to '@' parameter .

Please help in simple language

Comment: You'll have to show some code.  How are you calling the procedure?

Comment: Can you please show your work as well?

Comment: Need to see the code.

Comment: seem you are not passing `@Number` parameter in your code, better post ur c# code

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the @Number parameter to your command and set the value.

Here's an example of executing a stored procedure with parameters taken from MSDN.

```
static void GetSalesByCategory(string connectionString, 
    string categoryName)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        // Create the command and set its properties.
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
        command.CommandText = "SalesByCategory";
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // Add the input parameter and set its properties.
        SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();
        parameter.ParameterName = "@CategoryName";
        parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
        parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameter.Value = categoryName;

        // Add the parameter to the Parameters collection. 
        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

        // Open the connection and execute the reader.
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1:C}", reader[0], reader[1]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tyy0sz6b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)